# Texto do motivo da edição aparece "cortado" na fila de analise

Tags: bug

Hoje eu fiz uma edição para uma pergunta que estava `[pendente]`:

- [Erro ao compilar o Phalcon no AWS Amazon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126249/3635)

Com o seguinte texto (152 caracteres):

> Não coloque a resposta dentro da pergunta, não somos um fórum, somos um Q&A, pra criar uma resposta pra sua propria pergunta clique no botão "responder"

Mas na fila de analise ele aparece apenas 54 caracteres (talvez seja uma limitação) e fica assim:

> Não coloque a resposta dentro da pergunta, não somos u

Vejam como ficou:

<kbd>[image: BUG]</kbd>

Acredito que para o caso de edições que enviam a pergunta para fila de analise (equivale ao reabrir) o texto do motivo da edição é algo muito importante, as vezes aparecer cortado pode passar alguma interpretação errada da edição.

Por exemplo pode ser apenas uma edição para remover um link ou mensagem de saudação e as pessoas podem pensar que é uma edição para reabrir, então penso que devemos informar isso no campo de edição, além do motivo, mas o texto pode ficar grande e não aparecer na fila de analise.